# how to subtract system time from user defined time

Tags: java, android

can anybody suggest me to find interval between system time and user defined time as my hour =20 and minute =12.I just want to find interval between this two times and need to set this time for countdown timer

Answer (score 2):

To get difference between any two date/calendar objects it's better to get time in milliseconds(long).

```
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar usertime = Calendar.getInstance();
    usertime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    usertime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);

    long diffInMilisecond = Math.abs(usertime.getTimeInMillis()-current.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third party api, then [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) will hold very good for the above scenario. See [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html#Intervals_and_time_periods)

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all the trouble of having the user enter in the time he wants instead of how long from the current time? It makes more sense when mapping to the idea of a countdown timer.

If you want to set a timer for a user specified time this is how I would do it.

```
//Get user input into variable hours, and minutes
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        //do stuff when countdown has happened
    }, (((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60) * 1000)); //time in milliseconds to exec run
}
```

**EDIT**

If you simply want to calculate the difference in time when the user inputs hour and minute try the following:

```
//Get user input into variable hours, and minutes
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
//Assuming user inputs hour in 24 hour format and inputted time is in future
totalMinsDiff = (hours - cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) * 60 + 
      minutes - cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
countdownHours = totalMinsDiff / 60;
countdownMins = totalMinsDiff % 60;
```

Comment: Check the edit. I think that is what you are looking for. Getting more fields is just a matter of having the user input them and extracting the appropriate fields from the calendar.

Comment: MKJParekh has given me a perfect answer  for my requirement,anyway thx alot xshoppyx..